# Access 2010 missing menu cannot create accde

Tags: ms-access

I have edited an Access 2010 accdb file (changing the linked tables), which all works fine - all data now being read from/written to the new location.

I now want to create the accde. When I Save As I get the message:

"You cannot create .accde from a disabled database ... you can create it by using the message bar."

When I click on the message bar the whole menu disappears so I can no longer do a Save As and cannot create the .accde (nor anything else, of course). Whenever I open that .accdb file now the menu is missing. On screen I've only got the Form and, on the left hand side, the "All Access objects" column.

How do I get the menu back? The database is in a trusted location.

Thanks.

Comment: SOLVED: I used Alt+F11 to access the code, then entered the following code in the Forms' on load:

Comment: DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon", acToolbarYes